# What is the usage of client secret in azure active directory b2c?

Tags: oauth-2.0, jwt, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

What is the usage of client secret in Azure AD B2C? The Microsoft doc only said

> If your application exchanges a code for a token, you need to create
>   an application secret..

Will the azure ad b2c encrypt the token by the client secret, or if a native app requests a token need to send the client secret to the azure ad b2c endpoint?
And, does the client secret can be used to make only my trust native app can get the jwt then to visit my server, third part untrust app can't get the token from the b2c to visit my server?

and what is the usage of application id uri?

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It has nothing to do with whether you are using Azure AD or Azure AD B2C.

**client_secret** is required for web apps rather than native apps because client_secrets can't be reliably stored on devices.

It's required for web apps and web APIs, which have the ability to store the **client_secret** securely on the server side.

The official document: [Add a native client application to your Azure Active Directory B2C tenant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-native-application?tabs=applications) also doesn't mention that you need to add a client secret.

What you have seen in Microsoft doc is for web apps.

> and what is the usage of application id uri?

Application ID URI is the unique URI that is used to identify your API. When requesting an access token for this API, the whole URI should be added as the prefix for each scope.

If you have a web API protected and use another client app to access this API, you can enter the identifier used for your web API. See details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-tutorials-web-api?tabs=applications#add-a-web-api-applica).

Comment: Thanks your help. does it mean that, the azure b2c will encode the token with the client secret, and my t web server/api can decode the token with the client secret?

Comment: No. Your app can use the client secret to exchange an authorisation code for tokens after the user has authenticated. This only applies if your app is a back-end Web app though.

Comment: The tokens are signed with B2C's keys always, your app client secret has nothing to do with it.

Comment: As juunas said, client secret has nothing to do with this scene. Only you are using auth code flow for authorization, the client secret will be needed.